# Store variable in shared preferences and changes their value on different activities

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a practise 7 days exercise app. I set a progree bar on the main activity and want to change progress after days. Means if i complete exercise of day 1 ,progress bar set 15% . and when i complete day2 , progress set 30%.   I can do it without shared preference , it working correctlt but when after day1 complete i closed the app it again set progress from 0 . So i want to use shared preferences for this reason . Kindly someone guide me regarding this issue;

Comment: Please provide the code you tried to store the data in sharedpreference

Comment: `someone guide me` this is wrong place to ask for guide. Be more specific, what exactly is a problem for you?

Comment: Search by yourself about your problem and get your hands dirty first. If you still are unable to do it, then try the option of asking question on StackOverflow. Have a look at this thread though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: Thanks anath for giving meadvise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For Set Value to Shared Prefrence

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("ProgressBarData", 
MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("progress", 15);
editor.apply();
```

> for get value From Shared Prefrence

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(ProgressBarData, 
MODE_PRIVATE); 
int progress = prefs.getInt("progress", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

**1st ur know ur mistake**
u can't store ur data in local variable because at the end of the activity it destroyed every things and when u come back to android activity it will be started all thing once again and every thing is restarted

[https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle
read this u have better understanding

**Now ur solution**

if u want to store the data and process every day better to use local storage like 
Sqlite ,room or shared preference.

**Step to do the task**

There is three step to store, get and remove data into share preference

**For storing , getting deleting data**

```
//storing
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(name,Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(key, data);
        editor.apply();

//getting
SharedPreferences getSharedPrefrence = context.getSharedPreferences(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        int data = getSharedPrefrence.getInt(key, IntegerValuesAndStringValues.REGISTER_BEFORE_LOGIN);
        return data;

BasicFunctions.removeSharedPrefrences(getContext(),"Name of the preference");
```